# How to set shape in placeholder for non-deterministic array size

Tags: tensorflow

I want to train a data which varies array size. For example, Let's assume we wish to train sentences. The first sentence is "I am John" and The second one is "I know". If the sentences are converted into tensor. The first thing will become ["I", "am", "John"] and the next will be ["I","know"]. Consequently, the first array will need 3 as n_input for shape of placeholder. However, 2 is needed for the second array.

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])
```

I will need above codes for definition of placeholder. However, I can't determine n_input.

Additionally, What does None in shape mean? batch_size?
Please help me.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It seems like you want to use recurrent neural networks to train on variable lengths sequences but you seem a bit lost maybe you can start using Tensorflow tutorials ?

Comment: Approach with variable input size is not very common. If your data is very diverse in shape, consider using RNN (as jean mentioned above) or try to use scaling/padding, however it's not a very good way for text processing.

Comment: Please read the document which you will find reads that "shape: The shape of the tensor to be fed (optional). If the shape is not specified, you can feed a tensor of any shape."

Answer (score 13):

Technically the placeholder doesn't need a shape at all. It can be defined as such.

```
x =tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[])
```

In this case the place holder itself has no shape information to it.  If you know the dimensions of the tensor but not it's actual numerical shape we replace the numerical value of that dimension with None because it can have a variable size.

```
 x =tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None])
```

This affects some down stream static shape analysis that tensorflow does to get the shape information but otherwise it should still work as intended.

Comment: Thank you. And I have a question for transpose. In mnist tutorial, firstly placeholder x have been set as [None, n_steps, n_input], this means input data array (batch_size, n_step, n_input as I know. As the next step of mnist tutorial, x is transpose with [1,0,2]. I think x array will be transposed into (n_step, batch_size, n_input). My question is why the transpose is need.

Comment: I'm not sure which mnist tutorial you're referring to.  Could you please provide a link? Also if the question has been solved please mark it as done

Comment: @hackartist This transposition is done in the RNN-MNIST tutorial, because the rnn function expects a list of n_step x [batch_size, n_input]. This is described in the TensorFlow API documentation. But if you use the "newer" dynamic_rnn function instead, this transposition is not necessary anymore.

Comment: Why is it sometimes necessary to define the shape dimensions?

Comment: @Goldname because some functions in tensorflow are hardcoded to expect certain dimensions or expect shape information to be provided.  There isn't really a better answer and it could change whenever the API changes which is every release.

Answer (score 1):

In scenarios like yours, we usually make the second dimension(the time_steps or the input length) as a constant number, say the largest length of the sentence, and the blanks are fed with pads or zeros directly. Then you can set the placeholders as:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, max_input_steps])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, nax_output_steps])
```